# Alt & Title attributs in bigpic when mouse over thumbnails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm on Prestashop and using a pics gallery on products page. When I put mouseover thumbnails, the pic big changes. Thumbnails have Alt & Title with a name + an int : smarty.foreach.thumbnails.iteration

I need to put this int too in the big pic Alt & Title please.
Can we use javascript ?

**Here is the bigpic code :**

```
<img id="bigpic" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large')|escape:'html'}"{if $jqZoomEnabled && $have_image} class="jqzoom"{/if}
                         title="{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{if (count($images)) > 1} - image {$imgThumbIndex}{/if}"
                         alt="{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{if (count($images)) > 1} - image {$imgThumbIndex}{/if}"/>
```

**Thumbcode :**

```
{if isset($images) && count($images) > 0}
<div id="views_block" class="clearfix {if isset($images) && count($images) < 2}hidden{/if}">
    {if isset($images) && count($images) > 4}<span class="view_scroll_spacer"><a id="view_scroll_left" class="hidden" title="{l s='Other views'}" alt="" title="" href="javascript:{ldelim}{rdelim}">{l s='Previous'}</a></span>{/if}
        <div id="thumbs_list">
            <ul id="thumbs_list_frame">
            {if isset($images)}
                {foreach from=$images item=image name=thumbnails}
                {assign var=imageIds value="`$product->id`-`$image.id_image`" }
                    <li id="thumbnail_{$image.id_image}">
                    <a href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'img_thickbox')|escape:'html'}" rel="other-views" class="thickbox{if $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.first} shown{/if}" title="{$image.legend|htmlspecialchars}">
                    <img id="thumb_{$image.id_image}" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'img_medium')|escape:'html'}"
                        alt="{$product->name|htmlspecialchars} - image {$smarty.foreach.thumbnails.iteration}"
                        title="{$product->name|htmlspecialchars} - image {$smarty.foreach.thumbnails.iteration}" height="{$mediumSize.height}" width="{$mediumSize.width}" />
                    </a>
                    </li>
                {$imgThumbIndex = $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.iteration}
                {/foreach}
            {/if}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**I have some JS code in product.js**

```
if (domAAroundImgThumb.attr('href'))
{
    var new_src = domAAroundImgThumb.attr('href').replace('thickbox', 'large');
    var new_title = domAAroundImgThumb.attr('title');
    var new_href = domAAroundImgThumb.attr('href');
    if ($('#bigpic').attr('src') != new_src)
    {
        $('#bigpic').attr({
            'src' : new_src,
            'alt' : new_title,
            'title' : new_title
        }).load(function(){
            if (typeof(jqZoomEnabled) != 'undefined' && jqZoomEnabled)
                $(this).attr('rel', new_href);
        });
    }
    $('#views_block li a').removeClass('shown');
    $(domAAroundImgThumb).addClass('shown');
}
```

Can someone help ?
Thanks

Comment: `Mousse` au Chocolat? Try using a spelling checker (look at the title, too). Please use abbreviations sparingly. There seems to be something wrong with `pic big`.

Comment: You are right, it is <img id="bigpic"  and Thumbnails ;)